# Rename multiple Files iteratively in bash creates single file

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following files in my script's directory:

```
backup-001.bak backup-002.bak...backup-007.bak
```

I am trying to rename them in pure bash so that I get:

```
backup-002.bak backup-003.bak...backup-008.bak
```

I put together the following simple script which should iteratively rename said files; however, after I run it I end up with only one file `backup-008.bak`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
i=2
for file in backup-00[0-7].bak; do
    newname="backup-00$((i)).bak"
    mv -- "$file" "$newname"
  ((++i))
done
```

Comment: You must move in descending order (starting with 007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're renaming `backup-000.bak` to `backup-001.bak`. Then you rename `backup-001.bak` to `backup-002.bak`. This renames the file you created on the previous iteration. And so on through all the files, so you end up renaming `backup-000.bak` to `backup-008.bak`.

You should process the files in reverse order:

```
for ((i = 7; i >= 1; i--)); do
    oldname="backup-00$i.bak"
    newname="backup-00$((i+1)).bak"
    if [ -f "$oldname" ]
    then
        mv -- "$oldname" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

BTW, Linux has a program `logrotate` that can automate this.

Comment: Thanks! That makes it clear. Yes I'm aware there are any number of programs to do this automatically, I was just trying to do it in pure bash to learn.

Comment: Your code has a bug, it starts with `mv -- backup-007.bak backup-008.bak` and ends with `mv -- backup-000.bak backup-001.bak`

Comment: @LéaGris Why is that wrong? That's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Oh, I see. The original files start at 001, not 000. The OP's script uses `backup-00[0-7].bak` so I thought they started at `000`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in {7..1}; do
    mv "backup-00$i.bak" "backup-00$((i+1)).bak" ||
    break
done
```

Only works for 0-9 (or 100-200 etc) - bash arithmetic won't return zero padded numbers.

Comment: This will fail until all of the 7 backup files exist because the move of non-existent backup file will break out of the loop.

Comment: @LéaGris the backup files do exist, OP wants to rename them such that their number increases by one. Exisiting 7 is moved to non existing 8, existing 6 is moved to (now non exisiting) 7, and so on.

Comment: Your script does not move existing 7 to non-existing 8. Add `echo` before the `mv` and run your own script to see what it would move.

Comment: @LéaGris I did that before posting. I'm not sure what you mean. Note the order of `{7..1}` is descending.

Comment: my error, your script starts with moving 7 to 8.

Answer (score 1):

Considering a minimum index of 1 and a maximum index index of 7; here is a POSIX-shell friendly implementation with correct handling of backup roll and ignoring non-existent backup files.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

i=7
newname=$(printf 'backup-%03d.bak' $i)
while [ $i -gt 1 ]; do
  i=$((i - 1))
  oldname=$(printf 'backup-%03d.bak' $i)
  echo mv -f -- "$oldname" "$newname" 2>/dev/null || :
  newname=$oldname
done
```

Comment: OP is not trying to roll over their backups, they want to **increase** the number, presumably to squeeze something in at 01 (for some reason). That's the only way I can interpret their list of files and accepted answer.